# Nuvoton USB Isochronous communication

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I have Nuvoton M032SG8AE. It has USB peripheral so it supports USB communication. Nuvoton has sample project which is called HID_Transfer. However, it is quite confusing. I could not follow everything in the code. Nevertheless, I could communicate my microproccessor with my laptop using interrupt data transfer type.

I need to change the data transfer type from interrupt to isochronous for OUT operation.
I changed EP3's configuration from interrupt to isochronous.

```
    /*****************************************************/
    /* EP3 ==> Isochronous OUT endpoint, address 2 */
    USBD_CONFIG_EP(EP3, USBD_CFG_EPMODE_OUT | USBD_CFG_TYPE_ISO | 0x02);
    /* Buffer offset for EP3 */
    USBD_SET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP3, EP3_BUF_BASE);
    /* trigger receive OUT data */
    USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP3, EP3_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
```

I also changed the device descriptor settings from interrupt to isochronous.

**This is the full code**:

```
/******************************************************************************
 * @file     hid_mouse.c
 * @version  V1.00
 * $Revision: 11 $
 * $Date: 18/07/18 4:54p $
 * @brief    M031 series USBD driver Sample file
 *
 * @note
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 * Copyright (C) 2018 Nuvoton Technology Corp. All rights reserved.
 *****************************************************************************/
/*!<Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "NuMicro.h"
#include "hid_transfer.h"

uint8_t volatile g_u8EP2Ready = 0;
uint8_t volatile g_u8Suspend = 0;
uint8_t g_u8Idle = 0, g_u8Protocol = 0;
void taken_data(uint8_t* pu8EpBuf, uint32_t u32Size);

void USBD_IRQHandler(void)
{
    uint32_t volatile u32IntSts = USBD_GET_INT_FLAG();
    uint32_t volatile u32State = USBD_GET_BUS_STATE();

    if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_FLDET)
    {
        /* Floating detect */
        USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_FLDET);

        if (USBD_IS_ATTACHED())
        {
            /* USB Plug In */
            USBD_ENABLE_USB();
        }
        else
        {
            /* USB Un-plug */
            USBD_DISABLE_USB();
        }
    }

    if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_BUS)
    {
        /* Clear event flag */
        USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_BUS);

        if (u32State & USBD_STATE_USBRST)
        {
            /* Bus reset */
            USBD_ENABLE_USB();
            USBD_SwReset();
            g_u8Suspend = 0;
        }
        if (u32State & USBD_STATE_SUSPEND)
        {
            /* Enter power down to wait USB attached */
            g_u8Suspend = 1;

            /* Enable USB but disable PHY */
            USBD_DISABLE_PHY();
        }
        if (u32State & USBD_STATE_RESUME)
        {
            /* Enable USB and enable PHY */
            USBD_ENABLE_USB();
            g_u8Suspend = 0;
        }
    }

    if(u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_SOF)
    {
        /* Clear SOF flag */
        USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_SOF);
    }

    if(u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_WAKEUP)
    {
        /* Clear event flag */
        USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_WAKEUP);
    }

    if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_USB)
    {
        /* USB event */
        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_SETUP)
        {
            /* Setup packet */
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_SETUP);

            /* Clear the data IN/OUT ready flag of control end-points */
            USBD_STOP_TRANSACTION(EP0);
            USBD_STOP_TRANSACTION(EP1);

            USBD_ProcessSetupPacket();
        }

        /* EP events */
        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP0)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP0);
            /* control IN */
            USBD_CtrlIn();
        }
             
        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP1)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP1);
            /* control OUT */
            USBD_CtrlOut();
        }

        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP2)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP2);
            /* Interrupt IN */
            EP2_Handler();
        }

        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP3)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP3);
            /* Isochronous OUT */
            EP3_Handler();
        }

        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP4)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP4);
        }

        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP5)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP5);
        }

        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP6)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP6);
        }

        if (u32IntSts & USBD_INTSTS_EP7)
        {
            /* Clear event flag */
            USBD_CLR_INT_FLAG(USBD_INTSTS_EP7);
        }
    }
}

void EP2_Handler(void)  /* Interrupt IN handler */
{
    //HID_SetInReport();
}

void EP3_Handler(void)  /* Interrupt OUT handler */
{
    uint8_t *ptr;
    /* Interrupt OUT */
    ptr = (uint8_t *)(USBD_BUF_BASE + USBD_GET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP3));
    taken_data(ptr, USBD_GET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP3));
    USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP3, EP3_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
  * @brief  USBD Endpoint Config.
  * @param  None.
  * @retval None.
  */

void HID_Init(void)
{
    /* Init setup packet buffer */
    /* Buffer range for setup packet -> [0 ~ 0x7] */
    USBD->STBUFSEG = SETUP_BUF_BASE;

    /*****************************************************/
    /* EP0 ==> control IN endpoint, address 0 */
    USBD_CONFIG_EP(EP0, USBD_CFG_CSTALL | USBD_CFG_EPMODE_IN | 0);
    /* Buffer range for EP0 */
    USBD_SET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP0, EP0_BUF_BASE);

    /* EP1 ==> control OUT endpoint, address 0 */
    USBD_CONFIG_EP(EP1, USBD_CFG_CSTALL | USBD_CFG_EPMODE_OUT | 0);
    /* Buffer range for EP1 */
    USBD_SET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP1, EP1_BUF_BASE);

    /*****************************************************/
    /* EP2 ==> Interrupt IN endpoint, address 1 */
    USBD_CONFIG_EP(EP2, USBD_CFG_EPMODE_IN | INT_IN_EP_NUM);
    //USBD_CONFIG_EP(EP2, USBD_CFG_TYPE_ISO | USBD_CFG_EPMODE_OUT | 0);
     /* Buffer range for EP2 */
    USBD_SET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP2, EP2_BUF_BASE);

    /*****************************************************/
    /* EP3 ==> Isochronous OUT endpoint, address 2 */
    USBD_CONFIG_EP(EP3, USBD_CFG_EPMODE_OUT | USBD_CFG_TYPE_ISO | 0x02);
    /* Buffer offset for EP3 */
    USBD_SET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP3, EP3_BUF_BASE);
    /* trigger receive OUT data */
    USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP3, EP3_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
}

void HID_ClassRequest(void)
{
    uint8_t buf[8];
     int i;
    USBD_GetSetupPacket(buf);
     
    if(buf[0] & 0x80)    /* request data transfer direction */
    {
        /* Device to host */
        switch(buf[1])
        {
            case GET_IDLE:
            {
                USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP1, buf[6]);
                /* Data stage */
                USBD_PrepareCtrlIn(&g_u8Idle, buf[6]);
                /* Status stage */
                USBD_PrepareCtrlOut(0, 0); 
                break;
            }
            case GET_PROTOCOL:
            {
                USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP1, buf[6]);
                /* Data stage */
                USBD_PrepareCtrlIn(&g_u8Protocol, buf[6]);
                /* Status stage */
                USBD_PrepareCtrlOut(0, 0); 
                break;
            }
            case GET_REPORT:
//             {
//                 break;
//             }
            default:
            {
                /* Setup error, stall the device */
                USBD_SetStall(EP0);
                USBD_SetStall(EP1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* Host to device */
        switch(buf[1])
        {
            case SET_REPORT:
            {
                if(buf[3] == 3)
                {
                    /* Request Type = Feature */
                    USBD_SET_DATA1(EP1);
                    USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP1, 0);
                }
                break;
            }
            case SET_IDLE:
            {
                g_u8Idle = buf[3]; 
                /* Status stage */
                USBD_SET_DATA1(EP0);
                USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP0, 0);
                break;
            }
            case SET_PROTOCOL:
            {
                g_u8Protocol = buf[2]; 
                /* Status stage */
                USBD_SET_DATA1(EP0);
                USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP0, 0);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                /* Stall */
                /* Setup error, stall the device */
                USBD_SetStall(EP0);
                USBD_SetStall(EP1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/***************************************************************/
#define HID_CMD_SIGNATURE   0x43444948

/* HID Transfer Commands */
#define HID_CMD_NONE     0x00
#define HID_CMD_ERASE    0x71
#define HID_CMD_READ     0xD2
#define HID_CMD_WRITE    0xC3
#define HID_CMD_TEST     0xB4


#define PAGE_SIZE        2048
#define TEST_PAGES       4
#define SECTOR_SIZE      4096
#define START_SECTOR     0x10

#ifdef __ICCARM__
typedef __packed struct
{
    uint8_t u8Cmd;
    uint8_t u8Size;
    uint32_t u32Arg1;
    uint32_t u32Arg2;
    uint32_t u32Signature;
    uint32_t u32Checksum;
} CMD_T;

#else
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    uint8_t u8Cmd;
    uint8_t u8Size;
    uint32_t u32Arg1;
    uint32_t u32Arg2;
    uint32_t u32Signature;
    uint32_t u32Checksum;
}
CMD_T;
#endif

CMD_T gCmd;

static uint8_t  g_u8PageBuff[PAGE_SIZE] = {0};    /* Page buffer to upload/download through HID report */
static uint32_t g_u32BytesInPageBuf = 0;          /* The bytes of data in g_u8PageBuff */
static uint8_t  g_u8TestPages[TEST_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE] = {0};    /* Test pages to upload/download through HID report */

int32_t HID_CmdEraseSectors(CMD_T *pCmd)
{
    uint32_t u32StartSector;
    uint32_t u32Sectors;

    u32StartSector = pCmd->u32Arg1 - START_SECTOR;
    u32Sectors = pCmd->u32Arg2;

    printf("Erase command - Sector: %d   Sector Cnt: %d\n", u32StartSector, u32Sectors);

    /* TODO: To erase the sector of storage */
    memset(g_u8TestPages + u32StartSector * SECTOR_SIZE, 0xFF, sizeof(uint8_t) * u32Sectors * SECTOR_SIZE);

    /* To note the command has been done */
    pCmd->u8Cmd = HID_CMD_NONE;

    return 0;
}


int32_t HID_CmdReadPages(CMD_T *pCmd)
{
    uint32_t u32StartPage;
    uint32_t u32Pages;

    u32StartPage = pCmd->u32Arg1;
    u32Pages     = pCmd->u32Arg2;

    printf("Read command - Start page: %d    Pages Numbers: %d\n", u32StartPage, u32Pages);

    if(u32Pages)
    {
        /* Update data to page buffer to upload */
        /* TODO: We need to update the page data if got a page read command. (0xFF is used in this sample code) */
        memcpy(g_u8PageBuff, g_u8TestPages, sizeof(g_u8PageBuff));
        g_u32BytesInPageBuf = PAGE_SIZE;

        /* The signature word is used as page counter */
        pCmd->u32Signature = 1;

        /* Trigger HID IN */
        USBD_MemCopy((uint8_t *)(USBD_BUF_BASE + USBD_GET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP2)), (void *)g_u8PageBuff, EP2_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
        USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP2, EP2_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
        g_u32BytesInPageBuf -= EP2_MAX_PKT_SIZE;
    }

    return 0;
}


int32_t HID_CmdWritePages(CMD_T *pCmd)
{
    uint32_t u32StartPage;
    uint32_t u32Pages;

    u32StartPage = pCmd->u32Arg1;
    u32Pages     = pCmd->u32Arg2;

    printf("Write command - Start page: %d    Pages Numbers: %d\n", u32StartPage, u32Pages);
    g_u32BytesInPageBuf = 0;

    /* The signature is used to page counter */
    pCmd->u32Signature = 0;

    return 0;
}


int32_t gi32CmdTestCnt = 0;
int32_t HID_CmdTest(CMD_T *pCmd)
{
    int32_t i;
    uint8_t *pu8;

    pu8 = (uint8_t *)pCmd;
    printf("Get test command #%d (%d bytes)\n", gi32CmdTestCnt++, pCmd->u8Size);
    for(i=0; i<pCmd->u8Size; i++)
    {
        if((i&0xF) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf(" %02x", pu8[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");


    /* To note the command has been done */
    pCmd->u8Cmd = HID_CMD_NONE;

    return 0;
}


uint32_t CalCheckSum(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t size)
{
    uint32_t sum;
    int32_t i;

    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while(size--)
    {
        sum+=buf[i++];
    }

    return sum;

}

int32_t ProcessCommand(uint8_t *pu8Buffer, uint32_t u32BufferLen)
{
    uint32_t u32sum;
    
    USBD_MemCopy((uint8_t *)&gCmd, pu8Buffer, u32BufferLen);

    /* Check size */
    if((gCmd.u8Size > sizeof(gCmd)) || (gCmd.u8Size > u32BufferLen))
        return -1;

    /* Check signature */
    if(gCmd.u32Signature != HID_CMD_SIGNATURE)
        return -1;

    /* Calculate checksum & check it*/
    u32sum = CalCheckSum((uint8_t *)&gCmd, gCmd.u8Size);
    if(u32sum != gCmd.u32Checksum)
        return -1;

    switch(gCmd.u8Cmd)
    {
        case HID_CMD_ERASE:
        {
            HID_CmdEraseSectors(&gCmd);
            break;
        }
        case HID_CMD_READ:
        {
            HID_CmdReadPages(&gCmd);
            break;
        }
        case HID_CMD_WRITE:
        {
            HID_CmdWritePages(&gCmd);
            break;
        }
        case HID_CMD_TEST:
        {
            HID_CmdTest(&gCmd);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


void HID_GetOutReport(uint8_t *pu8EpBuf, uint32_t u32Size)
{
    uint8_t  u8Cmd;
    uint32_t u32StartPage;
    uint32_t u32Pages;
    uint32_t u32PageCnt;

    /* Get command information */
    u8Cmd        = gCmd.u8Cmd;
    u32StartPage = gCmd.u32Arg1;
    u32Pages     = gCmd.u32Arg2;
    u32PageCnt   = gCmd.u32Signature; /* The signature word is used to count pages */


    /* Check if it is in the data phase of write command */
    if((u8Cmd == HID_CMD_WRITE) &&  (u32PageCnt < u32Pages))
    {
        /* Process the data phase of write command */

        /* Get data from HID OUT */
        USBD_MemCopy(&g_u8PageBuff[g_u32BytesInPageBuf], pu8EpBuf, EP3_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
        g_u32BytesInPageBuf += EP3_MAX_PKT_SIZE;

        /* The HOST must make sure the data is PAGE_SIZE alignment */
        if(g_u32BytesInPageBuf >= PAGE_SIZE)
        {
            printf("Writing page %d\n", u32StartPage + u32PageCnt);
            /* TODO: We should program received data to storage here */
            memcpy(g_u8TestPages + u32PageCnt * PAGE_SIZE, g_u8PageBuff, sizeof(g_u8PageBuff));
            u32PageCnt++;

            /* Write command complete! */
            if(u32PageCnt >= u32Pages)
            {
                u8Cmd = HID_CMD_NONE;

                printf("Write command complete.\n");
            }

            g_u32BytesInPageBuf = 0;

        }

        /* Update command status */
        gCmd.u8Cmd        = u8Cmd;
        gCmd.u32Signature = u32PageCnt;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Check and process the command packet */
        if(ProcessCommand(pu8EpBuf, u32Size))
        {
            printf("Unknown HID command!\n");
        }
    }
}

void HID_SetInReport(void)
{
    uint32_t u32StartPage;
    uint32_t u32TotalPages;
    uint32_t u32PageCnt;
    uint8_t *ptr;
    uint8_t u8Cmd;
     
    u8Cmd        = gCmd.u8Cmd;
    u32StartPage = gCmd.u32Arg1;
    u32TotalPages= gCmd.u32Arg2;
    u32PageCnt   = gCmd.u32Signature;
     
    /* Check if it is in data phase of read command */
    if(u8Cmd == HID_CMD_READ)
    {
        /* Process the data phase of read command */
        if((u32PageCnt >= u32TotalPages) && (g_u32BytesInPageBuf == 0))
        {
            /* The data transfer is complete. */
            u8Cmd = HID_CMD_NONE;
            printf("Read command complete!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(g_u32BytesInPageBuf == 0)
            {
                /* The previous page has sent out. Read new page to page buffer */
                /* TODO: We should update new page data here. (0xFF is used in this sample code) */
                printf("Reading page %d\n", u32StartPage + u32PageCnt);
                memcpy(g_u8PageBuff, g_u8TestPages + u32PageCnt * PAGE_SIZE, sizeof(g_u8PageBuff));

                g_u32BytesInPageBuf = PAGE_SIZE;

                /* Update the page counter */
                u32PageCnt++;
            }

            /* Prepare the data for next HID IN transfer */
            ptr = (uint8_t *)(USBD_BUF_BASE + USBD_GET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP2));
            USBD_MemCopy(ptr, (void *)&g_u8PageBuff[PAGE_SIZE - g_u32BytesInPageBuf], EP2_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
            USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP2, EP2_MAX_PKT_SIZE);
            g_u32BytesInPageBuf -= EP2_MAX_PKT_SIZE;
        }
    }

    gCmd.u8Cmd        = u8Cmd;
    gCmd.u32Signature = u32PageCnt;
     
}

void send_data(void)
{
    uint8_t testData[64];
    uint8_t i;
    
    testData[0] = 1;
    
    for(i= 1; i < 64; i++)
    {
        testData[i] = i;
    }
    
    USBD_MemCopy((uint8_t*)(USBD_BUF_BASE + USBD_GET_EP_BUF_ADDR(EP3)),(void*)testData,64);
    USBD_SET_PAYLOAD_LEN(EP3,64);
}

void taken_data(uint8_t* pu8EpBuf, uint32_t u32Size)
{
    send_data();
}
```

I downloaded USB Trace application to see the data that I am sending from MCU to my laptop. There is nothing wrong when I am doing it with interrupt type data transfer. However, when I changed the setting from interrupt to isochronous I can't even see the USB port that is connected to the microprocessor's USB peripheral in USB Trace.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: @Bryan Alright. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I figured out that HID can't be used for isochronous data transfer type.That's why my program does not work.**